# Batch File iteration with Telnet

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a little batch file that execute this commands:

```
telnet testproxy.company.com 8080 >> test.txt
```

Now normally if it connects the command line doesn't give anything back (blank space and return to the normal dos behavior)
If not will give an error. (cannot connect)

In both the cases the generated test.txt doesn't show anything .

I want to create an iteration so if the connection to the proxy works will echo "okay it works" and write it into the text file.
In the opposite way will echo "doesn't work: and put in the same txt file.

Any suggestion?

I wanted to explain that I want to use some `IF` - `ELSE`. Example:

```
IF (the results of telnet is empty ECHO connection works) 
ELSE ( ECHO connection failed)
```

**P.S.** I tried with `telnet -f` but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should try MS PowerShell?

Comment: "*I could only use dos commands*"  - no you can't. The Windows command line has **nothing** to do with "DOS".

Comment: Sorry I wanted to explain that I want to use some IF - ELSE . 
example:
IF (the results of telnet is empty ECHO connection works)
ELSE ( ECHO connection failed) 

I hope is clear :)

Comment: Isn't there an `%errorlevel%` with telnet?

Comment: Let us not forget that the Windows TELNET client is not installed by default since Windows Vista.  So if you planned on distributing this batch file it may or may not work on your client computers.  I don't know who in their right mind would still be using telnet.  It is super unsecure.

Comment: @Squashman All the computers on the company network has for sure the Telnet. Do you think there's some alternatives windows commands to replace Telnet?

Comment: @Michael, you linked to a script that is not Windows based.

Answer (score 0):

Try running PowerShell script. I'm not too familar with it, but it works :)

```
$couldConnect = 0
$c = New-Object System.Net.TcpClient
try
{
    $c.Connect("testproxy.company.com", 8080)
    $couldConnect = 1
} catch
{
    $couldConnect = 0
}
```

Comment: I will try it and I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

How about checking ERRORLEVEL after running telnet?

```
telnet testproxy.company.com 8080 >> test.txt
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo ERROR: no connection
) ELSE (
    echo NB: connected, keep going
)
```